# How do I convert 24:10 - Monday to 00:10 - Tuesday in Python?

Tags: python

I want to know how to convert incorrect times (24h format) and days such as 
`24:10:00 Monday` to `00:10:00 Tuesday` in Python?

The file is modelled as below.

```
Time Monday Tuesday ... Friday
```

> i.e. I have a time column along with columns for all the days which
>   take value 0 (not on that day) or 1 (on that day).

These fields are written in a CSV file which I'll be reading into a data frame.

Comment: can you provide us more concrete data examples? what have you tried?

Comment: Basic process: first convert the time to an integer number of minutes (hour * 60 + minute). Divmod by 1440, the number of minutes in a day. E.g. 24:10 -> 1450 -> (1, 10) which means the time is 1 day ahead and 10 minutes into the day. Convert the latter back to time by divmod by 60 and get (0, 10) which you convert to 00:10. The 1 day ahead you use to advance Monday to Tuesday.

Comment: Incorporate the `datetime` module into your work; you can likely design it so that `24:10 Monday` simply doesn't happen, because `datetime` does the arithmetic properly for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def str_to_datetime(str_date):
    if date[:2] == "24":
        arr = str_date.split(' ')
        next_day_week = (datetime.strptime(arr[1], '%A') + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%A')
        str_date = '00' + arr[0][2:] + " " + next_day_week
    return str_date # if you want to convert the string to datetime --> # datetime.strptime(str_date, '%H:%M:%S %A')

str_date = '24:10:00 Monday'
str_to_datetime(date)
# output: '00:10:00 Tuesday'
```